# Exporting vector and raster in native projection

Tags: coordinate-system, google-earth-engine

I'm trying to export raster and vector in native projection and resolution. And I have made a code for it. After exporting both raster and vector versions of data, I have added them to ArcMap, but raster version does not lie geographically correct, it is shifted. I have tried to find a solution and I could not. Anyone you know why it is happening and how to solve it?

Please find the link below:
https://code.earthengine.google.com/33a783d191fefea8ef6c5956ddb01a01
[image]

```
var modis_col = ee.ImageCollection('MODIS/006/MOD13Q1').select('NDVI')
    .filterDate('2000-04-01', '2000-06-10');

var modis_ndvi = modis_col.max().divide(10000).gte(0.4).reproject(modis_col.first().projection());

var vis = {min: 0, max: 10000, palette: [
  'FFFFFF', 'CE7E45', 'FCD163', '66A000', '207401',
  '056201', '004C00', '023B01', '012E01', '011301'
]};

Map.addLayer(modis_col.first().clip(roi), vis, 'NDVI');
Map.addLayer(modis_ndvi.clip(roi));

var modis_ndviMasked = modis_ndvi.updateMask(modis_ndvi.gte(0.5));


var modis_ndvi_vector = modis_ndviMasked.reduceToVectors({
  geometry: roi,
  crs: modis_col.first().projection(),
  geometryType: 'polygon'
});

Map.addLayer(modis_ndvi_vector)


Export.table.toDrive({
  collection: modis_ndvi_vector,
  description: 'modis_ndvi_classed_2000_shp',
  fileFormat: 'SHP',
});

Export.image.toDrive({
  image: modis_ndviMasked,
  description: 'modis_ndvi_classed_2000_tif',
  crs: modis_col.first().projection().getInfo().crs,
  crsTransform: modis_col.first().projection().getInfo().transform,
  region: roi
});
```

Comment: Are they using "web Mercator"? EPSG:3857? Because of the north-south offset, it might be a difference between that and World Mercator, EPSG:3395. The latter uses the ellipsoid equations while the earlier one uses spherical equations.

Comment: @mkennedy, both raster and vector data use SR-ORG:6974